# Custom label format in a Axis in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Currently I'm having trouble creating multiple format in SSRS for one Axis. The current situation is that I have a measure that could bring a maximum value of 1.2M (Currency) but an average of 500K depending the period. Originally I have the labelformat property set to `0,,M`, but this doesn't bring the correct scale when the value is less than a million.

This are the current solution I have tried:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!Current_Year.Value, "CustomerSales") > Sum(Fields!Last_Year.Value, "CustomerSales"), 
IIF(Sum(Fields!Current_Year.Value, "CustomerSales") < 1000000, "0,K", "0,,M"), 
IIF(Sum(Fields!Last_Year.Value, "CustomerSales") < 1000000, "0,K", "0,,M"))

Public Function LabelCustomFormat(ByVal CY As Integer, ByVal LY As Integer) As String
   If CY > LY Then
    If(CY < 1000000) THEN
        Return "0,K"
    Else
        Return "0,,M"
    End If
   Else 
    IF(LY < 1000000) THEN 
        Return "0,K"
    Else
        Return "0,,M"
    End If
   End If
End Function
```

Is it possible to have the different scale in one Axis of a Chart? If so, please help.

Comment: What does "CustomerSales" refer to?

Comment: CustomerSales is the dataset that I'm using for the report.

Comment: I would expect the IIF code to work, if you use the Chart name insead of the dataset name.

Comment: It throws an error because the scope that the SUM function is expecting is a dataset related to the field.

Answer (score 0):

Well after trying to make a dynamic scale in the axis without success, I left the label format with the expression `0,,M` and set the interval to a **1M** instead of **500K**.